# Vertical slider can't be dragged to move on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

My first question ever so apologies in advance for anything incorrect or missing, I'm a total beginner.

I'm working on a mini JS/html app that includes a vertical slider (via transform:rotate) and on desktop, everything works fine, but on mobile (android, or chrome via device mode in developer tools) the thumb can't be dragged.

It's still possible to change the slider value by touching the slider track, but no longer possible to move the thumb by dragging. How can I get that working?

Here's minimal code to show the problem. The app is vanilla JS, ideally a solution would also be vanilla if JS is needed.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#slider-container {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10">
</div>
```

At first I thought it was because vertical dragging was triggering scroll behaviour, but it still happens even with overflow:hidden.

It must be something simple but I'm stumped after much googling...

Comment: Thanks for fixing the snippet Itay. I thought it was automagic but I see how to do it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue but finally, after hours and hours of searching, I finally found a blog post that described a solution that worked for me. The blog post can be found at https://dev.to/konnorrogers/creating-a-vertical-slider-using-input-typerange-1pen and the solution it discusses is simply to rotate the `<input type="range">` itself, *instead* of the parent container.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100px);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="10">
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me, although you still need to add something to override the default scroll behaviour well - right now the handle drags but the whole page scrolls at the same time for me (Chrome on android). Thank you for answering for future Googlers. I used some library for my project in the end, but don't remember what.